# Do I need sbt scala package builder for pyspark scripts?

Tags: python, scala, apache-spark, sbt

If I want to use spark with python and not scala, do I need the sbt scala build tool to assemble jar files so I can use those packages in my python script or do I need another tool? I have almost non-existent knowledge of java so getting into spark has been kinda complicated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SBT is Scala Build Tool. You don't need SBT if you are using PySpark.

SBT (and maven) are build tools for compiling and packaging scala & java applications.

Your python scripts for pyspark can't use jar files. You can directly submit your .py, .zip or .egg file(s).

http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html